# IMO proposal question. prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cos(\frac{2 \pi a_k} n) = 0$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, contest-math, roots-of-unity

I was looking into the problems from the art of problem solving by paul zeitz. I was stuck with the following question.

Let $n$ be a positive integer having at least two distinct prime factors. Show that there
is a permutation $(a_1,a_2, . .. ,a_n)$ of $(1,2, . . . ,n)$ such that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k  \cos\left(\frac{2  \pi  a_k}  n\right) = 0$$

I can see that we can use some arrangements of roots of unity multiplied with $k$ which can lead to sum $0$. Example for $n = 6$, we can do

$3+\omega+5\omega^2+4\omega^3+2\omega^4+6\omega^5=0$

where $\omega$ is a sixth root of unity.
I am not able to generalize this further.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: just added. sorry I am new to the platform.

Comment: Just want to say that there should be solutions in the AoPS forum where this problem was posted. And also having done IMO problems myself this does not look like an IMO problem format.

Comment: @IraeVid this isn't imo question. In the book it has been mentioned as IMO proposal question. book name: art of problem solving by paul zeitz. problem number: 4.2.38

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll show that there is a permutation $\pi$ of the roots of unity $\omega_1, \omega_2,\cdots,\omega_n$ such that $\sum k\pi(k)=0$. By taking real parts this solves the problem.

Write $n=ab$ for relatively prime $a>b>2$. We use the notation $\theta_c=e^{\frac{2\pi i \theta}{n}}$ for ease of typesetting. The idea is that
$$\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_n\}=\{a_c, 2a_c, 3a_c,\cdots,ba_c\}\cdot \{0_c,b_c,2b_c,\cdots,(ab-b)_c\}$$
Where we use the notation $S_1\cdot S_2=\{xy|x\in S_1, y\in S_2\}$. This is a number-theoretic statement, the proof of which is left to the reader (argue that all elements of the multiset on the RHS are distinct, and then count size). Now, suppose $\omega_k$ appears in the RHS as $(ra)_c\cdot (sb)_c$. We consider the permutation $\pi$ with $\pi(k)=\omega_{r+sb}$. The fact that this is a valid permutation is easy to see. Let $f(z)$ be a function so that $f(\theta_c)=\theta$, hence
$$\sum k\pi(k)=\sum_{s=0}^{a-1}\left((sb)_c\sum_{r=1}^b k(ra)_c \right)$$
Where $k$ is such that $\omega_k=(ra)_c\cdot (sb)_c$, i.e. $k=ra+sb\pmod{n}$.  Now the idea is that the inner summation is the same over all $r$. This is because it is equal to
$$\sum_{r=1}^b (ra)(ra)_c$$
As $\sum_{r=1}^b (sb)(ra)_c=sb\sum_{r=1}^b (ra)_c=0$, where the second equality comes from the fact that $\{(ra)_c\}$ is the set of $b$th roots of unity. Call this same sum $S$. Thus
$$\sum k\pi(k)=S\sum_{s=0}^{a-1}(sb)_c=0$$
Where the second equality comes from the fact that $\{(sb)_c\}$ is the set of $a$th roots of unity. I think we're done.